# Why are two 'this' not same?

Tags: javascript

```
var arrayfunc = [function(){return this;}];
var func = arrayfunc[0];
arrayfunc[0]();    //[function (){return this;}]
func();            //Window
```

i don't know why `this` is not same? Do you help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just think as below:

```
arrayfunc[0](); // this refer to arrayfunc
window['func'](); // this refer to window
```

Even through `arrayfunc[0] === func` return true, the caller is different.

`arrayfunc[0]();` called the function through the object `arrayfunc`,

`window['func']();` called the function through the object `window`.

Comment: "window.func()" is equal to "func()" ,so "this" is window.

Comment: i can't call anything like  window.XXX using ""var array =[function(){}];" . i know a little reason why it is not window, but i can't understand it is arrayfunc

Comment: @acjialiren As i said, you called the function through the object `arrayfunc`, so this is `arrayfunc`.

Comment: `var array_ = [[function(){return this;}],[function(){return this;}]];
array_[0][0]();`

is "this" array_ or array_[0]? i don't know how to Distinguish them

Comment: @acjialiren `this` is `array_[0]`.

Comment: :-(   `var array = [function(){...}]` the function is one of array's items but not its method. i can not understand why array can call that method . in my mind ,i say that array call method 'funcXXX' when calling method like `array.funXXX()`

Comment: @acjialiren In javascript, array is object too.

Comment: i know it is object. arrayfunc[0](); called the function through the object arrayfunc. arrayfunc[0] is one of arrayfunc's item but not its method.

Comment: @acjialiren No matter it is item or method, the real thing is that it is the property of the object, they are no difference, array index is only special property.

Answer (score 1):

Because this is a dynamic pointer to a function's scope. It is no fixed reference as in Java for instance.

Comment: i know what you say, but can you tell me something detail about my question

Comment: i find that arrayfunc[0] === func  return true , so i think they are same.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common misunderstanding. When you make an alias to a method - i.e., as you have, commit it to a variable - understand that you lose the `this` context in which the original method ran.

So for example:

```
var arr = [function() { alert(this[1]); }, 'hello'];
arr[0](); //'hello' - 'this' is the array
var func = arr[0];
func(); //undefined - 'this' is Window
```

Line 2 returns 'hello' because the method is running in the context of the array - since **we invoked it from within it**.

Line 4, however, invokes the same method but from the context of the alias we set up (`func`). This resets its context, so `this` points to the default - in a browser, this means `window`.

If you want to make a shortcut to a function but keep its context, you can do this with `bind()` (ECMA5 browsers only).

```
var func = arr[0].bind(arr);
func(); //'hello'
```

`bind()` creates a new function but bound to a particular context - in your case, the initial array it was taken from.

Comment: if "Functions are copied by value" is true ,why func === arrayfunc[0] retures ture

Comment: Poor wording on my part. They are of course reference objects; I was trying to say the context is not referenced - it is lost (in this case, reset to Window).

Comment: i can not understand 'context is not referenced'. arr[0] is a function ,but 'this' is the array

Comment: thanks very much. "func()" means "windows.func()" ,so "this" is window. And the function in array can not be called like "window.XXX",so "this" can not be "window". But i can not understand why it is array all the same.